# Connect to SAP HANA Database using VBA

Tags: excel, hana, mdxclient, vba

I am trying to fetch data into Excel from SAP HANA database using vba. I came across the below questions.

1. Do I need to install SAP HANA MDX Provider for this? If yes, please provide the link. I am unable to spot any.
2. What would be the vba script that I should write to connect to HANA DB?

Please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone who can help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done this with VBA as Excel has other ways to connect to HANA. Hope this helps:

- Using MDX: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/17/connecting-ms-excel-to-sap-hana-using-mdx/
- Using OData: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/02/sap-hana-on-a-whim-a-bing-map-in-my-ms-excel-from-an-anonymous-odata-service/

Cheers!